# Компендиум можно - с оговорками и кавычками - назвать тезаурусом?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Возникают специальные книги – каталоги смыслов. Первый из таких
>   компендиумов, то есть трудов, которые собирают и подытоживают некий
>   пласт информации, добытый предшественниками, издан в 1603 году  *(не
>   поняла; труд Рипы вышел в 1593 году)*; он был подручным справочником,
>   сборником сведений по мифологии, литературе и искусству. Эта
>   энциклопедия несет знаковые, схематичные изображения определенных
>   понятий. «Иконологию» Чезаре Рипы в первом издании можно читать прямо
>   в Интернете, точнее рассматривать. Потому что почти в каждом элементе,
>   который вы наблюдаете на полотнах, росписях, в скульптуре и
>   декоративных завитушках того времени, живёт смысл. И Чезаре Рипа
>   систематизировал эти знания. С помощью его каталога можно обнаруживать
>   значения знака и в разных контекстах. Этакий словарь понятий.

Что курсивом - это наше с автором, в текст не входит.

Меня интересует, на месте ли слова, характеризующие и выступающие как синонимы к компендиуму...

В конце - не заменить ли "этакий словарь понятий" на этакого тезауруса - ведь речь о постоянной взаимосвязи и перекличке смыслов?

---

[Словарь методических терминов](http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/az/)

> **ТЕЗАУРУС** (от греч. thesauros – сокровище, запас). 1. Словарь, отражающий смысловые связи между словами, терминами и другими
>   элементами языка. 2. Систематизированная совокупность понятий
>   определенной отрасли науки. Этот термин восходит к словарю английского
>   языка Р. Роже. Под Т. понимают также словарь, отражающий весь
>   словарный состав языка с исчерпывающим перечнем примеров употребления
>   слов в текстах. В методике этот термин используется и для обозначения
>   систематизированного запаса слов, необходимых для общения на заданную
>   тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Иконологию» Чезаре Рипы нельзя назвать тезаурусом, так как тезаурус - список ключевых слов по теме, идеографический словарь, в котором показаны семантические отношения (родо-видовые, синонимические и др.) между лексическими единицами, например, словарь синонимов, антонимов, Пушкинский словарь,"Словарь русского языка" Ожегова и т.д.

Компендиум - сборник статей, справочник. Например,сборник по вопросам демографической политики в мире, "Сборник по экологической статистике в африканских странах", "Поваренная книга", "Медицинский справочник". Компендиумом можно назвать "Энциклопедический словарь" - там коротко о разном. Не просто значение термина, но и сведения, с ним связанные.

"Иконология" - справочник, а не словарь.

Даты разные- невнимательность автора статьи, создал Чезаре Рипа "Иконологию" всё-таки в 1593 году, но как справочник по темам, а  в 1603 году был издан этот же труд, но статьи были уже по алфавиту и  с красочными иллюстрациями - гравюрами. Это уже была настоящая энциклопедия.